# How to prevent anaconda environment from reading libraries installed in local

Tags: python, anaconda

Python tries to read a library installed under `~/.local`, even though I am working on an anaconda environment.

```
> conda create -n testproj python=3.6
> conda activate testproj
> conda install pandas
> python
>>> import pandas as pd
```

Then I got an ImportError

```
ImportError: C extension: /home/myname/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/ ...
```

But if I change the permission of site-packages

```
> chmod 000 ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Then I can import `pandas` without any error. Namely Python is looking at outside of the anaconda environment.

**Question: How can I prevent Python from reading libraries outside the anaconda environment?**

Environment: openSUSE Leap 15.0

EDIT: I found that `sys.path` contains `site-packages` under `~/.local`. I do not think that the lines should be there.

```
['',
 '/home/myname/anaconda3/envs/myproj/bin',
 '/home/myname/anaconda3/envs/myproj/lib/python36.zip',
 '/home/myname/anaconda3/envs/myproj/lib/python3.6',
 '/home/myname/anaconda3/envs/myproj/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/home/myname/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/home/myname/anaconda3/envs/myproj/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/home/myname/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/myname/.ipython']
```

Comment: `source activate testproj`?  I don't believe you are actually in your newly created environment when you launch python.

Comment: bash: activate: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you on Windows/Mac/Other?  It would help if you copied your terminal window to help diagnose.

Comment: At least `python` shows "Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.". Therefore I am sure that I am using Anaconda. If I deactivate the environment, then `python` command starts Python 2.

Comment: Your environment name should be prepended to your command prompt, e.g. `(testproj) yourname:~ yourname$` And using `conda info --envs` will list all of your conda environments, with `*` next to the active one. `which python` should show you the location of the executable.

Comment: Such an information shows exactly what I expect. So I cannot understand why I have the problem.

Comment: @Alexander I think the OP is doing everything correctly: conda just doesn't support this (yet). It has to do with how the CPython bin spins up. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 9):

I get the same behavior on windows, clean environments include your user local packages. This is an open issue: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7173. `conda` doesn't support doing what you're asking directly (yet).

You can always just set the environment variable `PYTHONNOUSERSITE` (to any value), or invoke your interpreter with the `-s` switch, and you wont get your local packages (`~/.local` on windows is `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages`):

```
(test-env) C:\Users\matt>python -m site
sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\matt',
    'C:\\Anaconda440\\envs\\test-env\\python36.zip',
    'C:\\Anaconda440\\envs\\test-env\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Anaconda440\\envs\\test-env\\lib',
    'C:\\Anaconda440\\envs\\test-env',
    'C:\\Users\\matt\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages',
    'C:\\Users\\matt\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages\\some_lib-1.0-py3.6.egg',
    'C:\\Anaconda440\\envs\\test-env\\lib\\site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: 'C:\\Users\\matt\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python' (exists)
USER_SITE: 'C:\\Users\\matt\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

versus (note the `-s` switch, and now my local packages are no longer on my `sys.path`):

```
(test-env) C:\Users\matt>python -s -m site
sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\matt',
    'C:\\Anaconda440\\envs\\test-env\\python36.zip',
    'C:\\Anaconda440\\envs\\test-env\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Anaconda440\\envs\\test-env\\lib',
    'C:\\Anaconda440\\envs\\test-env',
    'C:\\Anaconda440\\envs\\test-env\\lib\\site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: 'C:\\Users\\matt\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python' (exists)
USER_SITE: 'C:\\Users\\matt\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: False
```

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am just reading similar issues on github and thinking what is the best solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

## Setting up a Conda environment to prevent the above issue on Linux

### Question/Description

I'm trying to set up a Conda environment on my Linux system. I found these steps helpful and would appreciate any guidance.

#### Steps 1

`source <PATH_TO_CONDA>/bin/activate`

###Step 2 Initialize Conda:

`conda init`

###Step 3 Auto-Activate Base Environment:

`conda config --set auto_activate_base True`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35451391)

Comment: This looks like a tutorial rather than a question

Answer (score 0):

Try defining [`PYTHONUSERBASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUSERBASE) explicitly, for example:

```bash
PYTHONUSERBASE=/dev/null python
>>> import pandas as pd
```

I always do that when I want to ignore local libraries and packages (defined in my `~/.local/` dir).